# send value to controller using html.actionlink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, actionlink

I am passing value from `Html.ActionLink` to the controller. But the problem is in controller, value is not being fetched. I don't know what is the problem.

Here is my code :

View :

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Copy", "Copy", "Item", new { id = item.Item_code}, null)
```

Contoller :

```
       public ActionResult Copy(int id)
       {
                 // Logic here
                 return View();
       }
```

Comment: This is really strange! Look at [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A9VEmd) fiddle it worked for me correctly. It might give you some tip to the resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You HTMLhelper looks OK, so that's strange. Please check a route for this link. Also type in the expected URL in browser address bar and see if you can get to controller. Also check URL when your mouse over the link. Does it show correct link?

You could try to use `Url.Action` instead of `Html.ActionLink` helper like below:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Copy", "Item", new { id = item.Item_code})"> Copy</a>
```

**Update**

Since you have ID like 001020002, try to change int type to string to see if it works that way:

```
   public ActionResult Copy(string id)
   {
             // Logic here
             return View();
   }
```

in View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Copy", "Copy", "Item", new { id = item.Item_code.ToString()}, null)
```

Comment: Hi..thanx for the answer. Url.Action did not work. :(

Comment: When I typed url in address bar, i get to controller. and link shows correct address when I move mouse over that link...

Comment: @Gokhale That's strange. What is the name of your controller where Copy action located?

Comment: It returns 'The resource can not be found' Requested URL: /Item/Copy/001020002

Comment: @Gokhale Post the URL along with your route configurations.

Comment: @Gokhale check updated answer, if it won't work please post your code from RouteConfig.cs to your question. And also embrace you Copy action with the controller class name in your question, please.